# What does "+0" mean of the earned bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

The following is a screenshot of earned bounties I got from [@TomMedley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319618/tom-medley)'s profile page. What does the **`+0`** means here as minimum bounty is `50`? Does it mean he initially got the bounty and then removed from the provider? But I do remember that bounty cannot be gotten back after given.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4482866/revisions shows he selected his own answer as the best one after offering a bounty. (Obviously, this doesn't give any reputation.)

Comment: If I recall correctly this was a way in the past to award the bounty to no-one. I believe you can no longer do this

Comment: @RichardTingle is correct. This is burried in the middle of the [relevant community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/).